# Object is not bool or equals false

Tags: c#-7.0

I'm using `C# 7.0` [`is` type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is). I'm trying to check if an `object` is **not** `bool` or the `bool` value equals `false`. However, the pattern I'm currently using with a `bool` type is:

```
if (obj is bool boolean && boolean)
{
    /* I'm not doing anything here */
}
else
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Is there a way to invert this `if` expression using the same type pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a [constant pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#constant-pattern):

```
if (!(obj is true))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```